# Redirect 301 on Plone CMS

Tags: apache

I changed one decade of URL based on Plone 4

I read all concerning Redirect 301 on Plone CMS questions on stackoverflow but i want to do it by the easier way possible like modify my virtualhost and insert lines

```
Redirect 301 old-url new-url
Redirect 301 old-url new-url
```

but i don't know where insert this lines in my virtualhost

I try different places but it seems not working

**My VirtualHost :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName    example.com
  ServerAlias   www.example.com
  ServerSignature On

  CustomLog     /home/log/example.com-access.log combined
  ErrorLog      /home/log/example.com-error.log
  LogLevel warn

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/icons/ - [L]

   RewriteRule ^/(.*) \
       http://localhost:8082/VirtualHostBase/http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/example/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
</IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyVia On

    <LocationMatch "^[^/]">
      Deny from all
    </LocationMatch>
  </IfModule>

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

  <IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
    #CacheEnable disk /
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

The idea is to put :

```
Redirect permanent http://www.example.com/old-url-xxx http://www.example.com/new-url-xxx
Redirect permanent http://www.example.com/old-url http://www.example.com/new-url
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried. This is a guessing game unless we can see the structure of your current host rules.

Comment: I edited with my virtualhost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immediately above your existing rewrite rule, add a rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^/old-url(.*) http://www.example.com/new-url$1 [L,R=301]
```

This redirects an entire section of URLs by matching the portion of the path after `/old-url/` (if any) and putting it on the end of the redirect URL.